# Как заэкранировать дефис в командной строке для Puppeteer, node, minimist?

Tags: node.js, debian, puppeteer

Надо выполнить примерно такую команду:

```
node some_script.js --param_1 '37.7790262' --param_2 '-122.419906' --param_3 'blablabla'
```

Проблема в том, что '-122.419906' не передается в скрипт.

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv);


param_1: 37.7790262,
param_2: true,
param_3: blablabla,
```

Если передавать просто 122.419906 без дефиса, то всё ок.
Как быть? Спасибо.

Comment: синтаксис `--имя=значения` этот ваш node.js не понимает?

Comment: нет, он понимает `some_script.js param1 param2`
Библиотека minimist делает возможность использовать  `--param_1 '37.7790262' --param_2 '-122.419906'`

Comment: ага, «это» называется minimist. ну что ж, смотрим в гугле, гугль показывает, что в [примерах есть использование нормального синтаксиса](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist): `node example/parse.js ... --beep=boop ...`. значит, используйте. удачи!

Comment: Так не получается же ведь, вместо '-122.419906' передается true.

Comment: передаётся-то всё правильно. и воспринимается этим вашим minimist-ом абсолютно корректно: `--имя -3.14` — это две опции: одна с именем `имя` и без значения (сам факт её наличия истолковывается как значение `true`), и вторая с именем `3` и значением `0.14`. а чтобы `--имя -3.14` воспринималось как **одна** опция, используйте синтаксис `--имя=-3.14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) можно использовать и «нормальный» синтаксис опций: `--имя=значение`.

пример:

```
$ node some_script.js --имя1=значение1 --имя2=-значение2 --имя3='значение3' --имя4='-значение4' --имя5=3.14 --имя6=-3.14
{ _: [],
  'имя1': 'значение1',
  'имя2': '-значение2',
  'имя3': 'значение3',
  'имя4': '-значение4',
  'имя5': 3.14,
  'имя6': -3.14 }
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Возможно сможете еще помочь с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205204/bash-3-event-not-found-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-debian