# -bash: !3: event not found в командной строке debian

Tags: node.js, debian

Пытаюсь запустить такую команду в debian:

```
node test_minimist.js --test='https://www.google.ru/maps/place/O'Reilly+Auto+Parts/@37.7660402,-122.4166835,15z/data=!3m1!5s0x808f7e2e3a6cdfcb:0x7edf0a3a2b4d2fb8!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sAuto+accessories%0A!3m4!1s0x808f7e2fcae1adf5:0x3cc471b8fd6f22bc!8m2!3d37.7660402!4d-122.4079288?hl=en'
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
-bash: !3: event not found
```

Что я делаю не так, как избежать этой ошибки? Спасибо.

Comment: если у вас внутри строки встречается символ одинарных кавычек, очевидно же, что использовать тот же символ ещё и в качестве ограничителя строки не стоит. используйте для этого символ двойных кавычек.

Comment: О, точно, не заметил, спасибо!!!